# What do these PowerShell Core Parameters Mean?

Tags: powershell, parameters, command-line-interface

In Windows 10 File Explorer, at what appears to be the recovery drive of this computer (I assigned drive letter R), I selected "PowerShell 7" > "Open here as Administrator," and when the prompt to allow the app to make changes to this device popped up, I read the Program Location entry as:

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoExit -RemoveWorkingDirectoryTrailingCharacter -WorkingDirectory "R:\!" -Command "$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle="PowerShell 7 (x64)"
```

What is the meaning of each parameter and value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***PowerShell (Core) 7*'s CLI, `pwsh`**, is documented in the conceptual **[about_Pwsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)** topic (analogously, *Windows PowerShell*'s CLI, `powershell.exe` - a subset of the former - is documented in [about_PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)).

The linked help explains the meaning of `-NoExit` (keep the session open), `-WorkingDirectory` (the startup working directory) and `-Command` (the command to execute on startup, which sets the console window's title).

However, **a parameter that *isn't* documented is

`-RemoveWorkingDirectoryTrailingCharacter`, whose sole purpose is to *work around a syntax problem***:

- In File Explorer / Desktop shortcut-menu definitions (defined via the registry), the folder at hand is represented as `%V`, which is expanded by the Windows (GUI) Shell to that folder's full path on invocation.
- While folders other than the root folder of a given drive are represented *without* a trailing `\` (e.g., `c:\foo`), *root* folders of necessity *do* end in `\`, e.g, `C:\`
- Since the shortcut-menu definition encloses `%V` in `"..."` so that the PowerShell CLI correctly recognizes folder paths even if they contain *embedded spaces* when passed to `-WorkingDirectory` (`-wd`), an expanded argument such as `"C:\"` *would break the invocation syntax*, because the trailing `\"` is interpreted as an *escape sequence*, i.e., as an escaped `"` char. rather than a verbatim `\` followed by a (syntactic) closing `"`.

The **workaround** is to insert an *auxiliary dummy character* - `!` - after `%V`, before the closing `"`, which avoids the syntax problem - but also *preserves* the dummy character.

The undocumented `-RemoveWorkingDirectoryTrailingCharacter` switch therefore instructs the CLI to simply strip the last character - the aux. dummy character - from the `-WorkingDirectory` argument received, yielding the original argument.

---

As you've discovered via [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5939#issuecomment-629686833), a **simple tweak to the command line would be sufficient to obviate the need for `-RemoveWorkingDirectoryTrailingCharacter`**:

- Change `"%V"` to `"%V\."`

While this expands to something like `"C:\\."` for root folders, the doubled `\` are benign (if you're passing a *literal* root-folder path, `"C:\\"` would be sufficient; the extra `\` then serves to *escape* the closing `"`).